# Using snowpack with the vue template but chrome dev-tools don't work with it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, snowpack

Using [snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) with the Vue template. Just set it up. But chrome dev-tools says it doesn't recognize it as 
vue.

I have deployed a basic Vue template app with vue-cli and this one get recognized as Vue. So the use Vue for local files is working correctly.

Not sure what it needs more or if it's something specific with snowpack

Comment: Using vue 3 and chrome dev-tools probably doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using vue 3 and chrome dev-tools probably doesn't support it yet.